# Determine the mod 5^3 roots of F(X) = 5X^3 + X^2 - 1 using Hensel's lemma

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine the mod 5^3 roots of F(X) = 5X^3 + X^2 - 1 using Hensel's lemma.

So far I have:

F'(X) = 15X^2 + 2X.

The mod 5 roots of F(X) are 1 and 4, bc 5|F(1)=5 & 5|F(4)=335

so the next step is to see if I can perform a lift to find the roots mod 5^2.

5 does not divide F'(1)=17 
and
5 does not divide F'(4)=248

so I believe this means I cannot perform a lift on either of these roots,

does this mean there are no mod 5^3 roots of F(X) = 5X^3 + X^2 - 1 ?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation to see how to use MathJax to properly typeset equations here. Note that a quick check shows that the only two roots in $\mathbb Z_{5^3}$ are $x=59$ and $x=61$. The MATLAB-Script to get these is `find(mod(5*(0:124).^3 + (0:124).^2 - 1, 125) == 0) - 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I discovered that when 5 does not divide F'(1) it is known that:

there exists some integer t such that F(1+5t) is a multiple of 5^2.

in this case t=2, F(11)=6775 which is a multiple of 25,

the there is an int t such that F(11+t*5^2) is a multiple of 125

again t=2, F(61)=1138625 is a multiple of 125, so 61 is a root.

Using the same process for F(4) gives the other root which is 59.